# JavaFX TreeView action listener

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, treeview

I have a `TreeView` of a file hierarchy and I want know when the user clicks on one of the items so that I can open that file in tab. This question has [already been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792090/javafx-treeview-item-action-event), but:

- it is from 2013, so the answers may be outdated (even though the accepted one [isn't](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#addEventHandler-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-))
- Simply adding a MouseListener is not enough for me, since users should be able to trigger the action using the keyboard as well as with the mouse

The documentation states I should add my listener to a custom `TreeCell`, but that class provides no listener methods, so I don't know how to go on from there. I am fine with answers that don't use `TreeView`, if there are any good alternatives.

Comment: “…but that class provides no listener methods…” Actually it does.  Have another look at [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeCell.html), particularly the “Properties inherited from class javafx.scene.Node” section.  See any property names with the word `Mouse` in them?  Also, the “Methods inherited from class javafx.scene.Node” section should contain inherited methods whose names start with `addEvent`.

Comment: You could add a listener to the TreeCells selected Property